# check_object_permissions with CreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

CommentCreate is a `CreateAPIView` used to post comments on another "report" model. I need to block anyone who is not the author of the report, or who is not in an assigned group of people who are allowed to post a comment, from using this endpoint to create comments.

```
class CommentCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    queryset = Comment.objects.none()

    def check_object_permissions(self, request, obj):
        if obj.report.creator != request.user:
            # also check if request.user is in the group of people that can comment
            raise exceptions.PermissionDenied(
                detail='You do not have permission')
```

The issue I'm facing is that `check_object_permissions` gets called, but the exception is not being caught anywhere, so the comment is posted as normal no matter what. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `check_object_permissions` is not called when a `Comment` is created.

Here is the full `create` code of the `CreateAPIView`:

```
class CreateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Create a model instance.
    """
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def get_success_headers(self, data):
        try:
            return {'Location': data[api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME]}
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            return {}
```

The `check_object_permissions` is only called in `get_object` which itself is only called when you try to retrieve an object vie the API.

In order to have a permission check in `CommentCreate` you should override the `perform_create` method in there and do the check:

```
class CommentCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    queryset = Comment.objects.none()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # untested if...
        if serializer.validated_data['report'].creator != self.request.user:
            raise exceptions.PermissionDenied(
                detail='You do not have permission')

        serializer.save()
```

Comment: I need to mention that inside perform_create you cannot anymore access serializer.data. You can only access serializer.validated_data before serializer.save(). please fix your answer :D